# all unique permutations of the tokens

Tags: python

Output all unique permutations of the tokens from part 1.
And the total number of permutations.

Example:

- This is a test
- This is test a
- This a is test
- This test is a
- This test a is
- Test is a This

do you know how to do it in python ?

```
import itertools
import itertools
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
def tokenize_word():
  sentence = str(input("please right a comment: "))
  punctuation = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
 
# Removing punctuations in string
# Using loop + punctuation string
  for element in sentence:
    if element in punctuation:
        sentence = sentence.replace(element, "")
  
  tokenize_sentence= word_tokenize(sentence)
  alphabetics_order_sentence = sorted(tokenize_sentence)
  for i in range(1, len(alphabetics_order_sentence) + 1):
    permutations= itertools.permutations(alphabetics_order_sentence)
    print(permutations)

tokenize_word()
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it mathematically? If yes, did you try it yourself? where did you get stuck? if no, then please understand the math behind it first, then ask your question again in regard the coding.

Comment: I have tried my code in python but doesn't give unique permutations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `permutations` from the package `itertools` (if package is allowed).

```py
from itertools import permutations

st = "This is a test"
result = list(permutations(st.split()))

for i in result:
    print(" ".join(i))
    
print()
print("The number of permutations is {}".format(len(result)))
```

Output from code above:

```
This is a test
This is test a
This a is test
This a test is
This test is a
This test a is
is This a test
is This test a
is a This test
is a test This
is test This a
is test a This
a This is test
a This test is
a is This test
a is test This
a test This is
a test is This
test This is a
test This a is
test is This a
test is a This
test a This is
test a is This

The number of permutations is 24
```